# pinch zooming for a UIWebView for ios 3.0 and newer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview, zooming

I've been reading about how to support the zooming for a webview, and i've found a lot of resources. And now i'm really lost.

What i've read:

- all you need is to enable the 'scales
  page to fit'
- add the uiwebview inside    a
  uiscrollview (while setting the
  minimum/maximum zoom scale and
  implementing - (UIView
  *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView
  *)scrollView)
- then you might need to handle the
  touchdown events...       manually
  then you might have to
  recognize them... manually... or
  using a gesture recognizer.

And apple documentation doesn't really help, and i can't really tell which ios are they talking about?
I'm really lost now.

So if some veteran in coco-touch (which is very rare to find) can guide us.

- Do i need a uiscrollview?
- What do i really need to implement?
- When would i need to capture touches
  events, recognize the gestures, and
  the zooming work.

And which is required in approximately which ios. Maybe this topic will help me and other people like me.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just enabling `scalesPageToFit` should do it; however, it's only possible to zoom to 100%, which also means that you can't zoom a page which is less than or equal to the screen size to begin with.

Comment: you're right, but i tried it before and didn't work. If it's in a custom viewcontroller in a tabbarcontroller. would things be different?

Comment: ok, it worked when i did a project with a uiwebview inside the root controller.
but it breaked when the UIWebview is in a viewcontroller inside a tabbarcontrolelr