# UIWebView pinch zoom not working beyond a certain limit

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am using a UIWebView to render html content. I have done the following to enable the pinch zoom on the UIWebView:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This has enabled me to enable pinch zoom and scrolling over the content of the .html page being rendered in the UIWebView.

But, there is a limit upto which I zoom in. I have found in the following link regarding the level of zooming in available in the following link:

[UIWebView Pinch Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646365/pinch-zooming-for-a-uiwebview-for-ios-3-0-and-newer)

Is there a way we can zoom beyond the limit of 100%?

Is there a different approach we can follow?

**EDIT:** I have tried setting the minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale of the ScrollView property of the UIWebView object, but still, that has not worked out. What could I be missing?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/44048558/3378413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using javascript using initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0  here  set your value

ViewDidLoad method

```
    NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><body bgcolor=#EAEAEA><font face='Myriad Pro' size='3'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0; user-scalable=YES'/>";
    NSString *endHtml=@"</font></body></html>";
    NSString *strDes=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",embedHTML,YourWebviewDescription,endHtml];
    [self.webViewObj loadHTMLString:strDes baseURL:nil];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", fontSizeSlider.value];  // I used sliderControl and its value is 1 to 5.
    [webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];
```

When we change the slider position (drag the slider)

```
   -(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
   {
       int font=(int)fontSizeSlider.value;
       NSLog(@"font %d",font);

       NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", fontSizeSlider.value];
       NSLog(@"string=%@",string);

       [webViewObj stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];

   }
```